# Python coroutines don't run concurrently with time.sleep()?

Tags: python, async-await, coroutine, python-asyncio

I'm trying to follow the examples at https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines; here is the code snippet which runs two `say_after` coroutines concurrently:

```
import asyncio
import time


async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    # time.sleep(delay)
    print(what)


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))


    print(f"Started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    await task1
    await task2

    print(f"Finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

If I run this, I get that the start and end are two seconds apart:

```
Started at 12:59:35
hello
world
Finished at 12:59:37
```

However, if I replace `await asyncio.sleep(delay)` with `time.sleep(delay)` (the commented-out line in the snippet above), I get that they are three seconds apart, and hence essentially running synchronously:

```
Started at 13:00:53
hello
world
Finished at 13:00:56
```

I don't quite understand this; isn't the point of having concurrent tasks that they run in parallel, even if the tasks themselves contain synchronous code? Why does this example no longer work with `time.sleep()` instead of `asyncio.sleep()`?

Comment: Why do you think `asyncio.sleep()` would even exist, if `time.sleep()` actually worked in an async context?  `time.sleep()` blocks the whole thread.

Comment: Non-blocking calls are needed, Time.sleep blocks the thread.

Comment: `time.sleep` is blocking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't quite understand this; isn't the point of having concurrent tasks that they run in parallel, even if the tasks themselves contain synchronous code?

Concurrency != Parallelism. When writing `asyncio` code, the underlying routines still have to yield flow back to the eventloop in order to allow concurrency. And the GIL is still there, regardless.

> Why does this example no longer work with time.sleep() instead of asyncio.sleep()?

The difference here is that `asyncio.sleep` suspends the current task, allowing other tasks to run. `time.sleep` does not, it's a "blocking" call. Programs using `asyncio` are still single-threaded (unless otherwise using threading), meaning `time.sleep` blocks execution in the main thread and blocks the entire program until the sleep duration has elapsed.

Coroutines afford *cooperative concurrency*, not parallelism.

To achieve good concurrency through coroutines, any code called within `asyncio.run` must be written in a non-blocking way. In practice, it means that any code run within a task has the responsibility to yield when it is a good time to pause execution, e.g. "I'm not doing anything useful because I'm just [waiting on I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html)" allowing another task to use the event loop.

Comment: An important point to make clear: `asyncio` is *cooperative* concurrency; if you don't do something to explicitly yield control back to the event loop (e.g. with `await`) then the event loop won't get a chance to run anything else until your code is *done*. If you choose to block on something that's not an async awaitable thing, the event loop has no way to know it *could* do something else, so it just keeps waiting for you to yield control back to it.

Comment: Compare and contrast with some *multitasking* implementations, where new tasks can interrupt ("context switch") running ones before they've finished, instead of waiting for them to end.

Comment: Incidentally, the difference between `asyncio.sleep()` and `time.sleep()` is also explained here: https://realpython.com/async-io-python/.